# Taking HTML input in flask and returning the data

Tags: python, html, function, flask, input

I want to take an input from a searchfield from a specific URL and run a function through it on Flask. However I constantly get 405 method not allowed, even though if I only run @app.route("/") the data returns like I want.

```
@app.route('/searchcountry', methods = ["GET"])
def single():
    return render_template("singlecountry.html")

@app.route('/searchcountry', methods = ["POST"])
def singlecountry():
    countrydata = request.form["textfield1"]
    alldata = allfacts(countrydata)
    return render_template("singlecountry.html", alldata = alldata, countrydata = countrydata)
```

Here I try to update the /searchcountry with the data that I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href="/home">homepage</a>
            <a href="/singlecountry">All data on one country</a>
            <a href="/comparedcountries">Compare two countries</a>
        </nav>
        <h1>Data about {{countrydata}}</h1>
        <h4>Data is collected from the WHO:<br><a href="https://apps.who.int/gho/portal/uhc-cabinet-wrapper-v2.jsp?id=1010501">Universal Health Coverage</a><br> 
            As well as the Happy Planet Index:<br><a href="http://happyplanetindex.org/">The Happy Planet Index</a></h4>

        <form id="search" name="search" action="." method="POST">
             <div id="searchfield">
                All data on a country:<br><input type="text"  name="textfield1">
           </div>
           <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <h3>{{countrydata}}</h3>
        {% for data in alldata %}
         <tr>
        <td>{{data}}</td>
             <br>
        </tr>
         {% endfor %}

    </body> 

</html>
```

My html code. I know the function works.

Comment: Try to use only one function for both methods

Comment: Each endpoint ('/searchcountry') maps to one view function. So only one rule is in the url_map. The other one (the 'single' function in this case) cannot be resolved and leads to this error. That is why @DrEichenbach his advice will work.

Comment: If I dont have the single function and only run with the singlecountry I get 405 method not allowed:
`@app.route('/searchcountry', methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def singlecountry():
    countrydata = request.form["textfield1"]
    alldata = allfacts(countrydata)
    return render_template("singlecountry.html", alldata = alldata, countrydata = countrydata) `